# How to prevent pagebreak in description environment

Tags: lists, page-breaking, description

I have a simple List in the description Environment.

```
\begin{description}
  \item [item] number one
  \item [item] number two
\end{description}
```

there is a new new page between the first item and the second. Is there a way to prevent this? I'd rather have the complete list coherent on a new page.

Comment: How do you want it to behave when there's more than a pageworth of items?

Answer (score 7):

```
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{description}
  \item [item] number one
  \item [item] number two
\end{description}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: @Nico: Try add more and more items until the minipage gets cropped. :-)

Comment: it seems the minipage is "eating" some vertical space after it. The next paragraph comes very close. Any solution for this ?

Comment: Use \par after the minipage