# Not breakable list across pages?

Tags: lists, page-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a list of unbreakable items?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4492/how-to-make-a-list-of-unbreakable-items)
>   [How to prevent pagebreak in description environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24655/how-to-prevent-pagebreak-in-description-environment)

My short list is split across two pages. Two bullets are on the end of one page, while the next two are on following page. That is, "A,B" on one page, "C,D" on the next:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\item D
\end{itemize}
```

How do I force the list (`itemize` or `enumerate`) to not break across pages?

Comment: You can always put the list in a `\vbox`, but it's not very `LaTeX`-ey.

Comment: There's also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24655/how-to-prevent-pagebreak-in-description-environment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example, using `\vbox`, which you can also replace with a minipage, using `\begin{minipage}` and `\end{minipage}`. The reason for me posting this particular example is to demonstrate that this might not be a typographically sound way of handling such problems. Modify the `bottom` on top of the example without the vbox and you can see the problems. Keeping the list contents together will either create underfull pages or overfull pages. Typographically is acceptable to break lists across pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bottom=2.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\vbox{%
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\item D
\end{itemize}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it does not work when "short line" is added before list

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: The reason why it works as-is in Yiannis' answer is because `\lipsum` issues a `\par` (a paragraph ending/beginning) giving a natural break between the text and the `\vbox`. If you were to enter a "short line" before `\vbox` *without* issuing some form of paragraph break, the `\vbox` will be set on the same line as "short line". Does any of the other suggested solutions (links above) provide an answer to your original question? Or, are you looking for something different?

Comment: @Werner Thanks, you've clarified me how it works :). Making end of paragraph after "short line" solves problem :).